# List only packages specifically installed by the user with apt (or other pkg man). Without dependencies nor default packages. Without using History

Tags: bash, package-management

So basically only the ones mentioned in commands such as `sudo apt install X` etc...

I have not seen any post on this. Only about all installed packages on the system regardless of them being dependencies or actually installed by me.

So if I have for instance only ever installed one package :

```
user@host 31/12/2019 00:33:15 :/sys/class/power_supply $ sai tlp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ethtool tlp-rdw
```

I would like to get only `tlp` and not `ethtool tlp-rdw`.

PS : I am looking for a solution that doesn't require the use of bash history. (cause : outside of history limit | multiple sessions overriding each other | old machine | friend computer | etc..)

Comment: @Cyrus How do you know that the asker is not using another Debian-based distribution that is off topic at Ask Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command in a bash shell to list all manually installed packages:

```
comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)
```

This command is compatible with operating system that use apt package manager. In the first sentence of the question you mentioned `sudo apt install`. I have assumed that your operating system uses apt, so the above command will run successfully on it.

This command is useful to prepare a list of manually installed packages for installation by apt on a different machine. Before installing the list of manually installed packages on a different machine it is a good idea to review the list and remove packages from the list that were installed but not used much, especially large packages that take a lot of disk space.